# Type casting exception in android

Tags: android

I got an exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to analytics.AnalyticsApplication

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Tracker mtracker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
        mtracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mtracker.setScreenName("Main Activity");
        mtracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Application cannot be cast to AnalyticsApplication`

Comment: You're most likely not setting the application in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

It's look like, you are missing binding part in Manifest. Look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) for `name` attribute.

When you are creating subclass of `Application` then you must specify that class name in your manifest file.

```
<application
    android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
    ... />
```

is equal to:

```
<application
    android:name="com.yournamespace.AnalyticsApplication"
    ... />
```